# what is the opposite of this logical statement

Tags: if-statement, logical-operators, simplify

I would like to check for the else condition only. Is there a way that I can simplify the code below?

```
      if (_endCurrentGoal && _startCurrentGoal && _startCurrentGoal === _startEffectiveDate && _endCurrentGoal === _endEffectiveDate) { //no statement );
       } 
       else {
          console.log("check for this code only");
       }
```

Is below code correct? is there a way to simplify it?

```
       if(!(_endCurrentGoal && _startCurrentGoal && _startCurrentGoal === _startEffectiveDate && _endCurrentGoal === _endEffectiveDate) {
          console.log("check for this code only");
       }
```

Comment: yeah, that's correct but I would prefer first approach

Comment: but I doesn't need to check for the first if statement. just need to execute the else statement

Comment: so sad, people just downvote my question.  it is not that I'm not trying to solve it

Comment: For me, first approach would be more clear. And as boolean operators are short circuit operator, it'll exit "if statement" if any expression from left to right would be false.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is this correct?” an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359466/why-is-is-this-correct-an-off-topic-question-and-what-should-i-ask-instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to distribute the `!` through the `&&`s.

That will look like this:

```
   if(!_endCurrentGoal || !_startCurrentGoal || _startCurrentGoal !== _startEffectiveDate || _endCurrentGoal !== _endEffectiveDate) {
      console.log("check for this code only");
   }
```